# Php: Concatenate string into all array items

Tags: php, arrays

I have [this](http://codepad.org/69O7bSbC) PHP snippet:

```
<?php
  $colors = array('red','green','blue');
  foreach ($colors as &$item)
  {
    $item = 'color-'.$item;
  }
  print_r($colors);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
  [0] => color-red
  [1] => color-green
  [2] => color-blue
)
```

Is it simpler solution ?

(some array php function like that `array_insert_before_all_items($colors,"color-")`)?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The method [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) will let you 'visit' each item in the array with a callback. With php 5.3 you can even use [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Pre PHP 5.3 version:

```
function carPrefix(&$value,$key) {
  $value="car-$value";
}
array_walk($colors,"carPrefix");
print_r($colors);
```

Newer anonymous function version:

```
array_walk($colors, function (&$value, $key) {
   $value="car-$value";
});
print_r($colors);
```

Comment: If you have no intention of using `$key`, don't declare it.

Answer (score 6):

Alternative example using `array_map`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

**PHP:**

```
$colors = array('red','green','blue');

$result = array_map(function($color) {
    return "color-$color";
}, $colors);
```

**Output (`$result`):**

```
array(
    'color-red',
    'color-green',
    'color-blue'
)
```

Answer (score 3):

For older versions of php this should work

```
foreach ($colors as $key => $value) {
$colors[$key] = 'car-'.$value; //concatinate your existing array with new one
}
print_r($sbosId);
```

Result :

```
Array
(
[0] => car-red
[1] => car-green
[2] => car-blue
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$colors = array('red','green','blue');

function prefix_car( &$item ) {
    $item = "car-{$item}";
}

array_walk( $colors, 'prefix_car');
```

It should work the same way you're doing it, albeit somewhat more sternly; array_walk gives an inkling more flexibility than manually looping.

Answer (score 0):

```
$colors = array('red','green','blue');

$prefix = "car-";

$color_flat = $prefix . implode("::" . $prefix,$colors);

$colors = explode("::",$color_flat);

print_r($colors);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$colors = array('red','green','blue');
$colors = substr_replace($colors, 'color-', 0, 0);
print_r($colors);
```

Comment: Please add a little bit of explanation of your code.