# how to add new values ​to the array by taking the existing values ​and adding data to the end of each value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with the values ​​`$arr = array ("1.", "2.")` and would like to add new values ​​to this array where the new values ​​will be the existing values ​​with an added value.

Example: `$arr = array("1.", "2.")` should transforms into `$arr = array ("1.", "2.", "1.1", "2.1")` .

Comment: Do you want to do it only for a single element or in a loop, all at once?

Comment: Related: [Php: Concatenate string into all array items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9850064/2943403)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a for loop

```
<?php
$arr = array("1.","2.");
$length = count($arr);
for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++)
    $arr[] = $arr[$i] . '1';
var_dump($arr);
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Functional approach:

```
<?php

$input = ['1.', '2.'];
$append = '1';

$out = array_merge(
    $input,
    array_map(function(string $val) use ($append) {
        return $val . $append;
    }, $input)
);

var_dump($out);
```

Run it live:
https://3v4l.org/TeRvN

How it works: It takes the input array (values '1.' and '2.'), adds the $append to each array element and merges with the original array.